# Error in Connection String because of quote marks

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, connection-string, sql-server-2014

I am getting an error because `"` is being applied multiple times in the following string:

`"C:\Users\Muhammad Kamran\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\shopping_website\App_Data\shopping.mdf"`

My Connection String is as follows:

```
SqlConnection con = 
    new SqlConnection(
       @"Data Source=LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\Muhammad Kamran\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\shopping_website\App_Data\shopping.mdf";Integrated Security=True");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote marks are always special..

Easiest method is to use the double quote

```
SqlConnection con = 
  new SqlConnection(
     @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=""C:\Users\Muhammad Kamran\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\shopping_website\App_Data\shopping.mdf"";Integrated Security=True");
```

You were also missing a bracket in (LocalDB) ...